# Android Studio - Configure local paths

Tags: ide, android-studio

I'm currently struggling to get Android Studio running on my windows box. The problem seems to be that I moved my home-directory to a different drive than C. (Because I have a tiny SSD for the system only and the rest is on my HDD)

I changed the gradle settings from android studio to the correct folder on drive E but when I try to create a new project this error pops up:

```
Failed to import Gradle project: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'. java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\myuser\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.6-bin etc.
```

I need the IDE to download it to E:\Users\myuser\etc.

Any idea where I can configure that? The settings from the settings dialog seem to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

it happens from time to time when gradle server has a bad day. Usually when they publish new version.

Comment: The directory "C:\Users\myuser\.gradle\" doesn't exist anymore. I moved my user directory to a different drive. How does that relate to the server?

Comment: when project is created gradle wrapper is copied to project folder. This is where script fails.

Comment: but why does it try to copy from a not existing directory? environment variables, regestry and settings are pointing to a different location.

Comment: My guess is remove all Android Studio and gradle config folders. I am not sure where they are created in Windows. My guess is user's folder or AppData. It looks like Gradle is looking to old repo path. If it doesn't pickup new path its a bug which needs fixing.